# React-router-dom problem with routes after creating app with react-create-wptheme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, react-router-dom

I have little problem with routing in my react app. 
I created app with `npx create-react-wptheme`.
WordPress was installed using mamp on mac.

So, here it is my code from index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Archive from './templates/Archive';
import Single from './templates/Single';
import Notfound from './templates/Notfound';

const routes = (
   <Router>
       <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Archive} />
            <Route exact path="/page/:slug" component={Archive} />
            <Route path="/post/:slug" component={Single} />
            <Route path="/search/:term" component={Archive} />
            <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

when I add basename parameter here : 
`<Router  basename="/your-site-wp-edition">`

finally first page start work and I can show my index page. but still other pages are redirecting me to 404 site.

I can't find any solution for this, can You help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is wordpress routes are conflicting with react router. You need to configure .htaccess/web-server to redirect to your home path '/', and let react take over from there.
This is normally how SPA works with a server.

You tell the web server to redirect all routes to /.

I don't have much experience with wordpress or php/apache but you can find more information in [SPA htaccess config](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/15006-single-page-app-htaccess-config/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked my .htaccess file, but I not saw anything bad here,

here it is my file, (and I run it on localhost) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your-site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I enabled rewrite rule in : `htpd.conf` 
`LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so`

And I found something about devServer, and I tried add this line :

`devServer.historyApiFallback = true;`

but this didn't help me with my issue.

I tried to move every item to App.js, and here created routing (I thought, maybe location was bad) but this give same result, just '/' link works properly